# Add tab between two text in body of mailTo function

Tags: c#, url, mailto

How can i add a tab value between two text which is in body of mail in mail-to function ?
For space i could use  `"%20"` and for break line i can use `"%0D%0A"` and space is being added and break line is added in the body of the mail

For tab, i tried to use `"%09"` but it doesn't work.
Content of the body i am trying to create at the server side.

Any suggestion for "tab" value which is supported in the